# PHP warnings after Mavericks upgrade

Tags: macos, command-line, php, osx-mavericks

After upgrading my Mac to Mavericks I've had a few small issues with machine, most of which I've resolved, however when I try to run PHP scripts at the command line I'm not getting these warnings...

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/yaml.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/yaml.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/apc.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/apc.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

The directory /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/ exists, but there is only xdebug.so & mcryt.so files in there.

I tried installing the yaml extension using `pecl` but it says it's already installed.

If I run `sudo php -a` rather than `php -a` then the other errors go away.  What permissions do I need to set on what folder to get this working for non-admin accounts?

Comment: Hi Toby. Are the extensions loaded when you sudo up the command? ie Show up in `sudo php -m`

Comment: Hi @AnthonySterling, the list of modules appears to be the same for both sudo, & non-sudo calls... https://gist.github.com/ToGri/0ce1d4b9ec437171eaab

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
diff /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

or

```
find /etc/* -name php.ini
diff /etc/.../apache2/php.ini /etc/.../cli/php.ini
```

Maybe there is some difference that gives you the answer.

Comment: Nope.  Just the one file used for both...

$ diff /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
    diff: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini: No such file or directory
    diff: /etc/php5/cli/php.ini: No such file or directory
    $ find /etc/* -name php.ini
    /etc/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

What's going on is that the error is conflicting with PHP versions. You must have had extensions leftover from a previous install of PHP.

What you can do is remove the `ext-intl.so` file from your older version of php. What I did was copy over the contents (chances are it's only `extension='/usr/local/Cellar/php55/phpx/`) to my `php.ini` file, comment those options out, and then remove the `ext-intl.so` files, fixing this issue.